# search query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i want to search with string like "love me" and i want result having this keyword row first

i tried

```
select *,(LENGTH(`Tags`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`Tags`, '% love %', ''))) / LENGTH('% love %')+(LENGTH(`Tags`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`Tags`, '% me %', ''))) / LENGTH('% me %') `occurences`
FROM `videos`
WHERE (Tags LIKE '% me %' OR 
Title LIKE '% me %' or Tags LIKE '% love %' or Title LIKE '% love %')
ORDER BY `occurences` DESC`
```

but its not working..

Comment: can you explain more and give some data with an example of the result you want

Comment: i have a two field in database and i want to search record with string there is multiple records in table but i want first record which having " love " and " 
me " keyword first and if any field having " love " keyword more then one times then that record appear first same as " me " keyword

Answer (score 0):

It would be really hard to specify a pure SQL query which does this, but since you are tagging PHP I expect you can also do some sorting in PHP to make it easier (unless your dataset is enormous).

First select your data then put all the data in an array then sort the data base on your criteria using usort: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Or if you have a large dataset then you could split the problem to first only select anything containing exact math for: LIKE '%love me%', then concatenate/join that with matches for: LIKE '%love%' AND NOT LIKE '%love me%' etc